# opendkim-genkey txt record in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dns, dkim

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 and generating keyfile using opendkim-genkey I've noticed the txt file is broken like:

```
myselector._domainkey   IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; "

"p=dhijvfhbdifg54t345t3456h3457" )  ; ----- DKIM key myselector for mydomain.com
```

I can only assume this is ok, but do I need to reformat this in my dns as before with all parameters in one block?  And does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: Ubuntu 14 is overall quite different for setting up email sending w/ opendkim / dovecot / postfix than Ubuntu 12. Different package names, config file locations, and (confusingly) even cert formatting.